# QML importing module

Tags: qt, import, qml, qtquick2, prefix

I want to import a custom module in my `main.qml` file. `Main.qml` is located under `"/"` prefix of my `qml.qrc` resource.

My custom module `Config.qml` is located within `Config` subdirectory. (`Config` directory is where `main.qml` is, i.e. `/path/to/main/Config/Config.qml`.

The `config.qml` and `qmldir` files are stored under the prefix `myPrefix` in the `qml.qrc` file.

```
Project
|- Config
    |- Config.qml
    |- qmldir
|- main.qml
```

Also I created a `qmldir` file which is according to the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html necessary. Here are my `Config.qml` and `qmldir` files.

**Config.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    property int myVariable: 10
}
```

**qmldir**

```
singleton Config 1.0 Config.qml
```

When I want to import my custom module as`MyModule` in the `main.qml` file.

```
import "???" as MyModule
```

How can I do that? Does someone have a suggestion?

**Edit:**

**qrc file**

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>main.qml</file>
</qresource>
<qresource prefix="/myPrefix">
<file>Config/qmldir</file>
<file>Config/Config.qml</file>
</qresource>
```

Comment: Isn't the module folder suppose to have same name as the module?

Comment: Also didn' work with import Config 1.0, when I changed to module Config

Answer (score 4):

** *Question has been changed after the answer of Arpegius to raise another issue, I answer this new issue.* **

This has nothing to do with *qrc-prefix*.
I believe your are mixing two different methods to import.

---

With or without prefix, to import a module you need to set the *import-path* of the QtQuick engine accordingly.

In your case, because your module directory is in the project-root directory :

```
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
// Now engine will look for subfolders which could be modules == with a qmldir
```

And in your main.qml you do the import using the prefix path instead of the filesystem path :

```
import myPrefix 1.0 as MyNamespace
```

---

You can also import simple QML files and not as a module :

```
// Because the path is relative to main.qml even in a qrc
import "myPrefix" as MyNamespace
```

Then you don't need the qmldir at all.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html):

> The module's qmldir file must reside in a directory structure within the import path that reflects the URI dotted identifier string, where each dot (".") in the identifier reflects a sub-level in the directory tree. For example, the qmldir file of the module com.mycompany.mymodule must be located in the sub-path com/mycompany/mymodule/qmldir somewhere in the import path.

So you should change `module MyModule` to `module Config` or import it within specific path:

```
import "./Config" as MyModule
```

Comment: I think the problem is, I have a prefix for the Config directory in the qml.qrc file and the import statement should also include the qrc:/prefix/... somehow. But I can't figure out how. Can you write an example with a prefix before Config directory?

Answer (score 0):

if this is still an issue for anyone, you to right click on the file and select add file to directory. then you select the directory you wish to add the qml file in. this directory should be the same as the main qml file. doing this solved my problem